# Clone Divs to reset after html ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, clone, reset

So, its kind of simple... but i can't think how to do it.

I have multiple divs in one page:

```
<div id="playerid-1"><a href="javascript:loadplayer(1);">[LOAD PLAYER]</a></div>
<div id="playerid-2"><a href="javascript:loadplayer(2);">[LOAD PLAYER]</a></div>
<div id="playerid-3"><a href="javascript:loadplayer(3);">[LOAD PLAYER]</a></div>
...
<div id="playerid-n"><a href="javascript:loadplayer(n);">[LOAD PLAYER]</a></div> //Every folder are different
```

in this divs I update html with ajax to load the player with this:

```
function loadplayer(playerid) {
$.ajax ({ 
    url: "/player.php?playerid=" + playerid + "&playerurl=" + $("#playerid-" + playerid).attr("data-src"), 
    cache: false, 
    success: function(html) {           
        $("#playerid-" + playerid).fadeOut("slow",function() { 
            $("#playerid-" + playerid).html(html); 
            $("#playerid-" + playerid).fadeIn("slow"); 
        }); 
    } 
});
}
```

To here It's WORKING But...
I want when i load another id of player to bring back the `[LOAD PLAYER]` link into the right div that already has loaded player

I try with `.clone()` option but i don't know how many `divs` I have
In my mind is this thing:

1. cloning every div with `preg_match` `(id="playerid-)`
2. `javascript:load player(x);` -> now will replace all divs with the cloned divs and load the player into the x div
3. `javascript:load player(y);` -> now will replace all divs with the cloned divs (in this step it will return player x to the default `[LOAD PLAYER]` link) and than load the player into the y div...

The problem here is that i don't know how to prey_match and foreach all divs into javascript variable with ids to use it in the `loadplayer()` function

Comment: man you edit my post wrong in some places...

Answer (score 0):

if you want to made a foreach on all the divs player why not to use:

```
jQuery("*[id^=playerid-]").each();
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eddiarnoldo/MnL2t/1/)

To know which divs to upload you could add a data attribute to them to see if they are with
a player, or just check the html on the each loop.

Comment: i think this wouldn't work because as i don't have the ids for [LOAD PLAYER] link

Comment: just to understant more, if I click on one [LOAD PLAYER] it will call the function with the id on the href and then it will do the ajax request to load the html of the player, what is the desired behaivor after this.

Comment: Yeah but could you explain me a little more this "To here It's WORKING But... I want when i load another id of player to bring back the [LOAD PLAYER] link into the right div that already has loaded player" as i understand if you click on another div it will call the function with another ID replacing [LOAD PLAYER] but it will leave the ones that already have a player with the html of the player.

Comment: Yes thats right... and i want to replace it back with [LOAD PLAYER] with the correct id, not with that id that is now clicked